Should it be "until" or "before" in "Go home until it's too late"?
Our Czech president wrote a sentence:

Go home Russians until it's too late.

There are many people discussing that it's grammatically wrong that there should be before. Is it really wrong?

Maybe the President intended irony? The expression before it’s too late is certainly a common one, so maybe it’s been intentionally tweaked to convey, “Go home (now), wait until your presence can no longer have the effect you desire, and then come back.”

That’s why it’s nearly always necessary to include in one’s questions here enough detail for others to grasp the context of the utterance. Without such context, it’s almost always impossible to answer any question with confidence.

@PaulTanenbaum Interesting thesis, but I'm sceptical.

You can stay until it's too late (to leave), but you can't leave until it's too late.  The verb must have the aspect of continuation if it's going to be used with "until it's too late" and used affirmatively.   Someone who doesn't want their sweetheart to leave could say "Don't leave ... until it's too late (to leave)".

Please cite your source. If the Czech president doesn't speak English well, you should also give this information.  Found one source: https://www.pravda.com.ua/eng/news/2023/04/30/7400051/ Over a year ago!

and another https://www.reddit.com/r/ukraine/comments/1333zk7/czech_president_petr_pavel_writes_message_on/ "There were many people discussing…”

I've seen on a T-shirt, which you can buy to support Ukraine in their fight against Russians: https://eshop.zapojmeukrajinu.cz/products/tricko-go-home

The president originally wrote it on a launcher that was being sent to Ukraine from the Czech Republic. He has continually been supporting Ukraine in their fight against Russia. So it wasn't ironic. He can speak English very well but still it's possible he made a mistake.

@LucieKefurtová It's not uncommon for non-native English speakers to get their prepositions mixed up, even if they are otherwise decent English speakers. I assume it often happens because a single word in their language translates to multiple English words, and they use the wrong one.

When I lived in Czechia as an English speaker, I noticed Czechs saying "until" instead of "by" or "before": for instance, "please fill out this form until the deadline." It seems to be quite common over there, although it's definitely wrong.

@wobtax Intriguing; if this is a common enough regional pattern, then a descriptivist view would not say it's "wrong." If you can find more support for this, it may well be the best answer to this question, and makes more sense than "a world leader with seemingly good English skills made a basic error."

@AndyBonner You're right: all I mean is it's non-standard in the US and Britain. I'll see if I can find more support for this pattern.

@wobtax Looking him up, Petr Pavel studied in the US and Britain and got a degree from Kings College. It's not impossible to suppose that the usage was a mistake, but a lot easier to suppose that it's regional.

@wobtax That (mis)use of "until," where native speakers would use "by," is also very common among Germans speaking English. The same preposition is used for both cases in German.

What's more of a mystery to me than his usage of prepositions is, he doesn't know Russian or what? Why would he write such a thing in English, to whom? (Btw I like the idea that he actually meant "go home, sit on your backside until you don't have any chance with this war anymore, and then you can try again", in the best laughing beast tradition. But I guess he just had a brain fart.)

@wobtax "please fill out (and submit) this form until the deadline" is an interesting example. I added "submit" to fill in the implied meaning. With a little tweak it becomes more idiomatic: "please fill out (and submit) this form at any time until the deadline" - and in the latter case, substituting "before" works equally well. However, in the president's statement, "too late" isn't a fixed point in time, so I couldn't find a way to rephrase it to sound natural.

@Divizna, I don't know whether the Czech president speaks Russian, but even if so, there's some reasons to use English instead: perhaps it's intended for the world audience, or perhaps a refusal to use the recipient's language carries a political subtext?  Or perhaps what we're reading is someone else's translation of Czech or Russian source?

@TobySpeight Not a translation, his direct words from his own hand. And let me remind you that the guy was a career soldier when Czechoslovakia was part of the Warsaw pact, so I kinda doubt he could slack off through the compulsory Russian in primary school and then be done with it. Refusing to use the recipient's language makes sense as a power move for negotiations, not for insults (those you should want to deliver in such a way they can't pretend they didn't get).

"It was intended for world audience" is my problem with it exactly: He didn't tell the Russians where to go. He only mimed doing so for the uninvolved viewers on the gallery. It was a purely performative, self-serving gesture. I'd have more respect for it if he wrote it in Czech.

It is not grammatically wrong — it just means something other than what the speaker probably intends.
Let us say that 2 o’clock is “too late”.
“Go home until it's too late” means “Go home and stay there until at least 2 o’clock.”
“Go home before it's too late” means “Go home, ideally right now, but certainly before 2 o’clock.”
I am pretty sure the Czech president meant the second.
As other people have noted “before it’s too late” is a pretty common phrase.  I have never heard anyone saying “until it’s too late”, but I could invent a scenario: Sally wants to find Bob so he can fulfill his promise to go to the movies with her at 7pm.  Bob does not want to see the movie, so his friend, who is sure Sally does not know where Bob lives, advises him “Go home [where you won’t be found] until it’s too late [to see the movie].”  Pretty contrived but grammatically correct and it would sound perfectly idiomatic.

Part of what makes this confusing is that it's idiomatic to use "go home" to mean "go home and stay there". E.g. "go home until you're feeling better". Taking that completely literally doesn't make sense- by the time you feel better, you'll have already finished going home. In the case if this quote, "before it's too late" means "go before it's too late" whereas "until it's too late" is the idiomatic shortening of "go and stay there until it's too late".

"Don't wait until it's too late" seems like a reasonable usage (albeit with a different meaning).

I don't know anything about this quote except what the poster wrote here. I don't have any context. But just based on what's given here ...
There is a stock phrase in English, "before it's too late". Meaning, you should do whatever now while you have a chance, because sooner or later circumstances will change and it won't be possible to do it any more. Like, "This sale ends Thursday. Buy now before it's too late!"
"Until it's too late" doesn't make much sense. If you wait "until it's too late", that means that you're waiting for a time when it is no longer possible to do what you want. You could say this of someone else. Like, "I hope my opponent delays taking this action that will hurt me until it's too late."
Maybe if we had the context, it would be apparent that that, or something like that, is what the president of Czechia meant. Or perhaps his English is not perfect and he just made a mistake.

The OP’s is right.  It should be before:

Go home, Russians, before it's too late.

Until is used, for example, in such a construction:

Don't VERB until it's time.


But it’s possible that taunting humor was meant. Check out my comment to the OP.

Yes, it's wrong.  (Or at least, it probably doesn't mean what the Czech president intended.)
As other answers say, ‘before it's too late’ is a common phrase.
‘Until it's too late’ is also fairly common; but doesn't mean quite the same.
The most obvious meaning implies that the action of going home should continue until it's too late — which doesn't make sense, as it's not a journey that could be maintained indefinitely.
Alternatively, you could read it as telling Russians to go home and stay there until it's too late — implying that they should leave their homes at that point.  Which also seems unlikely to be what the president meant.
But it's hard to tell from just that one potentially-inaccurate sentence.

That definitely sounds wrong to me.
The word "until" usually denotes an endpoint—a time that a particular thing stops. The phrase "go home until" would usually be interpreted as indicating when a person can leave home again. For example, if I told someone "Go home until noon," that would mean that they should go home and wait until noon, and then at noon, they can come back.
So by saying "Go home, Russians, until it's too late," the president seems to be saying that the Russians should go home, and then wait until it's too late, and then they should come back to Ukraine. That is probably not what he meant!

There is a legitimate use for 'until it is too late', but the meaning is different.   Example: The children wanted to watch the television show but they played outside until it was too late.
In math equations 'before is is too late' means all expressions 'less than'.
Whereas 'until it is too late' means 'equal to or greater than'.

It’s wrong! However, if you want to express that you should go home before it becomes too late, "before" would be more appropriate. So, "Go home before it’s too late" is likely the clearer option for conveying that you should go home prior to the point where it becomes too late.

The correct sentence would be:
"Go home, Russians, before it's too late.".
Or:
"Leave now, Russians, before it's too late."
The sentence "Go home Russians until it's too late" is a bit unconventional, but it's not entirely grammatically wrong. However, it's understandable that some people might find it awkward or unclear.
It's worth noting that in spoken language, especially in emotional or emphatic contexts, people often use more informal grammar or sentence structures, which can be effective in conveying their message. So, while the sentence might not be perfect from a grammatical standpoint, it's still a powerful statement!

In standard English, it should be “by” or “before.”
But using “until” in this context seems to be a regional pattern in Czechia. Anecdotally, when I lived there I heard people using “until” where a native speaker would say “by” or “before”: for example, “please submit the form until the deadline.”
I found examples from Czech sites by searching "until the deadline" site:.cz in DuckDuckGo and Google:

“Apply for the internship through our online form and please attach your CV including references, motivation letter, PhD project’s description to add to the application until the deadline on the 15th April 2024, 11:00 AM Czech time.”   — Nadace Neuron (archived
link)
“The payment has to be at least authorised until the deadline, although the money will arrive only in several days.” — Masaryk University Faculty of Informatics (archived link)
“Print out the application form, sign it and hand it in together with all the required attachments ... until the deadline.” — Univerzita Palackého v Olomouci Faculty of Medicine and Dentistry
(archived
link)

Indeed, this usage appears in Czech government documents:

"In the last Report on Water Management in the Czech Republic
we failed, due to lack of time, to make an evaluation of those
waters until the deadline of this report." — Ministry of Agriculture of the Czech Republic (I wasn't able to archive this one, unfortunately)
“Embassy of the Czech Republic in India appeals to all suppliers of chemical substances to  kindly pre-register your substances until the deadline on 31 May 2018 with ECHA (European Chemical Agency).” — Embassy of the Czech Republic in New Delhi (archived link)

However, I can find Czech sites on English usage that distinguish between “until” and “by” the same way US speakers do (example 1, example 2, example 3).

I don't think this is a regional thing, it's just a mistake common to speakers with a different native language. German speakers often make the same error. I don't know Czech so I can't say but in Germany it's because the word you'd use in German means both until and before.
